# AutoHotKey - clik on image

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to change `send {Browser_Back}` to a mouse click in a specific image / or a specific point (pixel).

```html
SendMode , Input
SetMouseDelay , -1
SetBatchLines , -1
Loop
{
    ImageSearch ,,, 0 , 0 , A_ScreenWidth , A_ScreenHeight , mor.png
    bT := ErrorLevel ? bT : 1
    ImageSearch ,,, 0 , 0 , A_ScreenWidth , A_ScreenHeight , NewPic2.png
    bT := ErrorLevel ? bT : 1
    ImageSearch ,,, 0 , 0 , A_ScreenWidth , A_ScreenHeight , NewPic3.png
    bT := ErrorLevel ? bT : 1
    If bT
    {
        bT := 0
        Send , {Browser_Back}
        Sleep , 100
}   }
Return
f1::ExitApp
```

Comment: Do you want to click on one of the found images or a specific place not related to the image?

Comment: If finds one of these three images- clik in a different place not related to the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random clicking in the given area

x, from pixel to pixel, 
y, from pixel to pixel

example

```
Random, x, 1130,1300
Random, y, 580, 680
Click %x% %y%
```

Comment: A good answer should include some explanations, not just a piece of code.

Comment: In addition to what the others have said, this also doesn't answer your original question, which was to "mouse click in a specific image / or a specific point".

Answer (score 0):

No problem, just replace the `Send , {Browser_back}` line with `Click , 500 , 500`. Replace the 500s with the x- and y-coordinates of where you want to click.

Comment: I understand more or less ... and is there a bigger area than just 1 Pixel? that there will not be excessive repetitions? and how do I set coordinates? according to the program the appropriate Pixel is x1100 y350 .. counting from the top left screen.

Comment: It will click every time it finds the image and it will repeat until the picture is no longer found. The default action for click position is from the top-left of the active window, which appears to be what you want.

Comment: it looks like it works ... one point ... you can do to enter many such points the script itself chose randomly? and do a print screen before clicking?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want it to click one of a few locations randomly and also do a print screen after finding an image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54533030/autohotkey-process-priority-radom-sleep