# How to set AutoHotKey process priority & radom sleep?

Tags: process, autohotkey, sleep

I want to set the high priority on the script below (only first).

Another important thing is whether you can do a `Radom Sleep, 250 to 350`??

```
Loop
{
    {
        ImageSearch,,, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, mor.png
        bT:= ErrorLevel ? bT : 1
        If bT
        {
            bT:= 0
            Random, x, 1130, 1300
            Random, y, 580, 680
            Click % x % % y %
                Sleep, 500

        }
    }

    ImageSearch,,, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, biz.png
    bT:= ErrorLevel ? bT : 1
    {
        bT:= 0
        Random, x, 540, 618
        Random, y, 419, 430
        Click % x % % y %

                 }
}
Return
f1:: ExitApp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
Process, Priority,, High 

Loop
{
    If GetKeyState("F1","P")
        ExitApp
    ImageSearch,,, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, mor.png
    bT:= ErrorLevel ? bT : 1
    If bT
    {
        bT:= 0
        Random, x, 1130, 1300
        Random, y, 580, 680
        Click %x%, %y%
        Sleep, % rnd(250,350)   
    }
    ImageSearch,,, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, biz.png
    bT:= ErrorLevel ? bT : 1
    If bT
    {
        bT:= 0
        Random, x, 540, 618
        Random, y, 419, 430
        Click %x%, %y%
    }   
}

rnd(min,max){
    Random, myVar,% min,% max
    return myVar
}
```

Untested.

Comment: I realize some of the code is from OP and untested, but it looks like there may be a missing `If bT` after the second `bT:= ...`. +1 for using a function.

Comment: @Evan: Feel free to edit the answer  or add another one.

Comment: Understood and edited. I'm still pretty new to SO (and SE in general) and didn't even realize I could make edits to others' posts. I suppose that is better than pointing it out in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the priority of the thread the script is running on so that it can/cannot be interrupted by another thread, you use the `Thread` command:

> `Thread, Priority, Level`

Where `Level` is a signed 32 bit integer. See [AHK — Thread.](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Thread.htm)

You can generate a pseudo-random number using the `Random`command (as you already are in your code). If you want to pause the thread using random numbers, you do it like so:

```
Random, timer, 250, 350    ; Generates the pseudo-random number
Sleep, %timer%               ; Pauses script execution according to value
```

Comment: Sleep is a command and [variables in commands](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s61) have to be enclosed in percent signs: `Sleep, %timer%`. The command [Critical](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Critical.htm) is generally superior to the sub-command `Thread, Priority, Level`. The OS's priority level for the entire script can be changed via [Process Priority](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Process.htm#Priority): `Process, Priority,, High`

Comment: I'm green, what should it look like in this script?